# Dynamically change the labels map based on basemap chosen?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using Google Maps API v3, how do I programmatically change the labels of my map based on the basemap I'm using?

In order to change the Styles of my map, I use the following code:

```
var Map_Style = //JSON format containing my map style;
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: {lat: -19 , lng: -43.5},
    }); 
map.setOptions({styles: Map_Style}); //Applying the custom style to my map.
```

As you can see, the labels are clearly displayed, with the topo basemap.
[image]

But when I change to the satellite basemap, the labels are obfuscated by the Aerial Image:
[image]

So, what would be the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very doable. You just need to use a map [event listener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#EventsOverview). Inside the listener, call your function that will change the map style. Sample of listeners are click, dblclick, drag, mouseover, etc.

Here's a sample:

```
function initMap() {

   var myLatlng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
   var customMapTypeId = 'custom_style';
   var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType([
      {
        stylers: [
          {hue: '#890000'},
          {visibility: 'simplified'},
          {gamma: 0.5},
          {weight: 0.5}
        ]
      },
      {
        elementType: 'labels',
        stylers: [{visibility: 'on'}]
      },
      {
        featureType: 'water',
        stylers: [{color: '#890000'}]
      }
    ], {
      name: 'Custom Style'
  });
  var customMapTypeId = 'custom_style';


  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  });
 //listener for mouse click,etc
  map.addListener('click', function() {
     //execute your Style map change 
      map.mapTypes.set(customMapTypeId, customMapType);
      map.setMapTypeId(customMapTypeId);
  });
}
```

What's gonna happen here is that the Map Style (labels ,etc) will change when you click your mouse button. Here's a [reference to labels, events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType) that might help.